# Chrome Print-Preview fails with jQuery print button

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have a kiosk with the following Greasemonkey (Tampermonkey) code on the page to enable receipt printing:

```
$("input").css("font-size", "xx-large");
$("#newcheckout").append ('<div id="autoCheckOrder"></div>');
$("#autoCheckOrder").append ('<button>Print Receipt?</button>');

var loanTable = $("#loanTable")
var loanHTML  = loanTable.html().replace(/(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})/g, "<br><b>$1</b>");

$("#autoCheckOrder button").click ( function () {
    var newWin      = window.open (""); 
    newWin.document.write ( "<!DOCTYPE html>" );
    newWin.document.write( "<html>" );
    newWin.document.write( "<head>" );
    newWin.document.write( "<title>" );
    newWin.document.write( "</title>" );
    newWin.document.write( "<style>" );
    newWin.document.write( "@media print { " );
    newWin.document.write( "body { " );
    newWin.document.write( "background-color: white;" );
    newWin.document.write( "height: 100%;" );
    newWin.document.write( "width: 60mm;" );
    newWin.document.write( "position: fixed;" );
    newWin.document.write( "top: 0;" );
    newWin.document.write( "left: 0;" );
    newWin.document.write( "margin: 0;" );
    newWin.document.write( "padding: 15px;" );
    newWin.document.write( "font-size: 14px;" );
    newWin.document.write( "line-height: 18px;" );
    newWin.document.write( "}" );
    newWin.document.write( "}" );
    newWin.document.write( "</style>" );
    newWin.document.write( "</head>" );
    newWin.document.write( "<body>" );
    newWin.document.write ( loanHTML ); 
    newWin.document.write( "</body>" );
    newWin.document.write( "</html>" );
    if(newWin.print()) {
        newWin.close();
    } else {
        newWin.close();
    }
} );
```

This works fine in Firefox -- not in Chrome beta 19. Just updated it today. You press the 'print' button, the print preview appears and says:

> Print Preview Failed, Please Use system dialog.

**UPDATE**

See Brock Adam's answer below, then the following *working* code below ( CSS only for brevity ):

```
@media print {
    body {
        background-color: white;
        width: 55mm;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0;
```

...etc.

Comment: Is this possibly due to an 'undefined' issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the CSS.  You've got:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
```

-- which tries to put the content at the extreme top left of the page, which is not allowed for whatever printer you are using (or just about *any* physical printer).

Change any one of those 4 CSS parameters to put the start of the printout within whatever margins your printer accepts.
If you comment out the auto-print and auto-close parts of the Greasemonkey script, you can use Chrome's DOM tools to see that the print-preview fails and then adjust the CSS until it works.

Obviously, Chrome is more persnickety, whereas Firefox defaults to moving and sizing the printout as necessary.  There *might* be a setting you can set for Chrome, maybe.  (I don't know and refuse to invest too much effort into [Grab-All™](http://www.sluggy.com/comics/archives/daily/090106) products.)

Comment: But it works as written in Firefox/greasemonkey. I will try changing it though.

Comment: Remember that all browsers behave differently, and that getting something pixel-by-pixel-the-same between browsers is a fool's errand.  It doesn't matter where the original script works.  The answers says why it doesn't work on Chrome -- and it doesn't actually have anything to do with the script or GM in this case.  Any page with CSS like that would have the print-preview problem in Chrome, using most printer drivers.

Comment: Am about to test this. Appreciate the advice. Will report results.

Comment: Eureka! I comment out the style and the problem goes away. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure which of the offending css rules was causing this ...tried this one and that, finally commented all of them out. The results are acceptable and I'm calling it 'a wrap'. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: You're welcome.  If you decide you need the CSS again, then adjust the margins until it works.  EG:  `margin: 1in 0.75in;`.